# How to append two nullable arrays

Tags: c#, console-application

I am troubling in appending two nullable arrays.

the case is below.

```
int?[] array1 = new int?[1000];//having some values till index 500
int?[] array2 = new int?[100];//having some values till index 50

/*so, the total logical size of appended array should be 1000 but physical size of an array should 550 */

//I tried this...

int StoreIndex;//here i store null index number of array1.
for (int i = 0; array1.Length; i++)
{
    array1[StoreIndex + 1] = array2[i];
    if (array2[i] == null)
    {
        break;                
    }

}
//but this coding give me unhandled exception of type'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
```

Anyone explain what I doing wrong here?

Comment: You never initialized `StoreIndex`.

Comment: array1.Length > array2.Length, hence the exception

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Concatenating the entire arrays or only indexes that have a value?

Comment: O.k I got this                                                                                     array1.Length > array2.Length, hence the exception – Giorgos Betsos

But any idea for correction in my coding for achieve my task.

Comment: What exactly is your task?

Comment: I think i define case very carefully. i Also explain the necessary things too.

Comment: You need change `array1.Length` to `array2.Length`. see my answer

Comment: Are you trying to mimic this LINQ query in a more optimal way? `var result = array1.Concat(array2).Where(i => i.HasValue).ToArray();` ? What should happen if index 4, as an example, contains a `null` but index 5 contains a value? Should it copy the null or should it skip it?

Comment: See my edit answer, I add the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
array2.CopyTo(array1, StoreIndex);
```

**Other way:**

Change `array1.Length` to `array2.Length`

```
int StoreIndex;//here i store null index number of array1.
for (int i = 0; i< array2.Length; i++)
{
    array1[StoreIndex + i] = array2[i];
    if (array2[i] == null)
    {
        break;                
    }

}
```

Comment: This will give the same index out of range exception if there's too many non-null values in array2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join those 2 arrays just use LINQ:

```
int?[] array1 = new int?[1000];
int?[] array2 = new int?[100];
int?[] newArray = array1.Concat (array2).ToArray();
```

If you want to get all not `null` values from both try this:

```
int?[] array1 = new int?[1000];
int?[] array2 = new int?[100];
int[] newArray = array1.Concat (array2).Where (x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray ();
```